# .htaccess RewriteRule for category/page in custom CMS

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working RewriteRule that rewrites any page to the literal url:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is I want to add page=$1&category=$2 and convert it to...obviously... /category/page

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&category=$2 [QSA,L]
```

**I should note that I would still like to be able to access pages without categories - ie /login or /about that should go to index.php?page=about for instance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the contributions...

Because I needed to cater for both /page and /category/page...I ended up doing this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-][^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

But that was only half the solution as I needed to modify my PHP to check whether category is set or not and to send a 404 if it doesn't match. Otherwise `/invalid_category/valid_page`would still work.

The ideas above all pushed me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will be as below.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]
```

> Input url : http://www.test.com/my-cat/my-page
>
> and it will be treated as : http://www.test.com/index.php?page=my-cat&category=my-page

Comment: One question...what if we want to access /login for instance? Or a page with no category?

Comment: Then we should go with prefix over here. Like this

`RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
    #https://www.example.com/index.php?category=9&page=CBSE `#https://www.example.com/category/page/CBSE`


Method One:

    #use this code for generate new url 

RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

    Method Two :

    RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2


    Note :Hit Your Url index.php?category=$1&page=$2 to convert $i & $2 Create Dynamic Url Your Id Bases
```

Comment: Thanks so much...will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below, we are instructing apache to don't look for directory or file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&category=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

If you want to generate rewrite urls easily, there are a lot online rewrite url generators.

Comment: Funny enough never searched for that. Will definitely check it out.

Comment: what if we want to access /login for instance? Or a page with no category?

Comment: For that you can add another route like you added for products. But I feel it's better if you add a suffix to your product rewrite url so you can leave other routes intact. Ex: to the product rewrite url, you can add a suffix like product/category/page.